# Unable to reinstall xfce or any GUI from Ubuntu 18.04 tty

Tags: package-management, xubuntu, dependencies, xfce, gui

I am trying to reinstall xfce or xubuntu-desktop on Ubuntu 18.04 on TTY after unfortunately and mistakenly removal of my GUI packages and potentially more. My sources list currently looks like:

```
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-proposed main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

The output of `apt policy ubuntu-desktop` is

```
ubuntu-desktop:
Installed: (none)
Candidate: 1.417.5
Versiontable:
1.417.5 500
500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates.main amd64 Packages
```

After running `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` I  tried to install xubuntu-desktop with `sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop` and `sudo apt-get install xfce4`which gives me a list of dependencies all of which it says that it "is not going to be installed". For example:

```
    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
    xfce4: Depends: xfwm4 (>= 4.12.0) but it is not going to be installed
    ...
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

To attempt to investigate this broken packages problem, I tried:

```
sudo apt-get install -f && sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

and

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep hold
```

which returned **nothing**. I also tried `sudo apt-get install aptitude` as a workaround but I got:

`E: Package 'aptitude' has no installation candidate`.

I know I can manually install these dependencies with `sudo apt-get install <unmet dependencies> <unmet dependencies>` but I will forever be stuck in a loop of doing this for hundreds of dependencies.

Am I missing something in my sources list that would result in me not being able to 1) install packages like aptitude and xfce? 2) install dependencies? I am not really sure what to do next.

As a note: I am new to Ubuntu! Also, I am indeed connected to wifi.

Comment: Your first sources list is incorrect. You need a 'main' at minimum there as well as the 'universe' you have.  You've not included standard Ubuntu *bionic* 'multiverse restricted' either, including those packages only if security updates, backports are available, but NOT if they haven't been upgraded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at your sources.list

You've included multiple repositories for backports, security & updates, but they are missing from the main *bionic* release, meaning if you remove packages on the original media, you won't be able to re-install them (unless in 'universe'; eg. aptitude is found in 'main').

try

```
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-proposed main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

Note: I've used the formatting of your post; it's not how mine would look.

Key is you need to add 'main' to the first line, though I'd also add 'multiverse' & 'restricted' too

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

*I don't think this is your only issue; it doesn't explain xfwm4*

Comment: This worked! I added the main bionic release to my sources list, installed xubuntu-desktop and rebooted to the GUI working. Thank you so much, I really really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your `sources.list` is missing the line

```
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted multiverse
```

I also see, you have the `proposed`-repository enabled, normally that shouldn't be the case. But you may have your reason. In doubt, disable the `proposed`-repository.